# How to disable FCM on spesific activity Android

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service

i want to ask about FCM. I have an FCM service that is running as it should this is my code

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "ch1")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("ch1",
                getString(R.string.app_name), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

but i want to disable this notification on spesific activity, for example i have ChatActivity. where if i get notificatin on this activity, the fcm service is not showing a notification. I have tried implement this code but still not work

```
if(!(this.getApplicationContext() instanceof ChatActivity)){
   //build the notification
}
```

anyone have solution for my problem? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all keep a flag in your `SharedPreferences` for `ChatActivity` to know if it's open or not.

Now inside `ChatActivity` set this flag `true` in `onResume()` and `false` in `onStop()`. Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    AppPreferences.getInstance().setBoolean("IS_CHAT_ACTIVITY", true);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    AppPreferences.getInstance().setBoolean("IS_CHAT_ACTIVITY", true);
}
```

If you don't know anything about `SharedPreferences` check [This Tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shared-preferences-in-android-with-examples/).

Now in your `FCM Service` class, you have `onMessageReceived()` callback, which is triggered every time a notification comes.

Now Do this in your `onMessageReceived()` callback:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        if (AppPreferences.getInstance().getBoolean("IS_CHAT_ACTIVITY", false)) {
            //Do Nothing, Ignore Notification
        } else {
            //Write code to show notification here
            //Show Notification
            generateNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification());
        }
    }
}
```

That's it, that's how you can prevent the notification while you’re on `ChatActivity`.

Comment: hello, thanks for your response. i think with this code will work. However, it made me think of using static values ​​in a class. thank you brother!